# Multiple 'Inner Join' with openquery

Tags: inner-join, openquery

Im trying to translate an SQL query to OPENQUERY. I have this code that works well:

```
Select
    F_ART.CODART,
    F_ART.REFART,
    F_ART.DESART,
    F_LTA.PRELTA,
    F_STO.DISSTO,
    F_PRO.NOCPRO,
    F_FAM.DESFAM,
    F_SEC.DESSEC
From
    [LINKED]...F_ART Inner Join
    [LINKED]...F_FAM On F_FAM.CODFAM = F_ART.FAMART Inner Join
    [LINKED]...F_LTA On F_LTA.ARTLTA = F_ART.CODART Inner Join
    [LINKED]...F_PRO On F_PRO.CODPRO = F_ART.PHAART Inner Join
    [LINKED]...F_SEC On F_SEC.CODSEC = F_FAM.SECFAM Inner Join
    [LINKED]...F_STO On F_STO.ARTSTO = F_ART.CODART
```

I want to transform it to use OPENQUERY so I have tried this code:

```
Select

CODART,
REFART,
DESART,
IMGART,
DISSTO


From
    OPENQUERY ([LINKED], 'SELECT * FROM

F_ART Inner Join
F_STO On (F_STO.ARTSTO = F_ART.CODART)
')
```

But when I add the next Inner Join sentences it fails.

Can I use multiple Inner Join with openquery?

Im using this code from MS ACCESS to query a Linked SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this creting a 'View' in the SQL server.

That 'View' contains all the 'Joins' needed.

Then I create the query pointing to the 'View'.